# is it possible to replacing the script or attaching the more function to script inside DOM

Tags: javascript

This is an exasmple. A script is loading inside `</body>` tag from the file that i can't edit.

```
<script>
(function() {

//something

})();
</script>
```

I want to execute the script on scroll, or mouseover which i usually achieve by doing this. (Basically i want to load the above script like the script below)

```
</script>
var eventList = ["mouseover", "scroll"];
for(event of eventList) {
    document.addEventListener(event, myFunction); 

}
function myFunction() {
  (function() {

   //something

  })();

  document.removeEventListener('mouseover', myFunction);
  document.removeEventListener('scroll', myFunction);
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to achieve that by replacing with the help of javascript? or please suggest me any answer that is helpful. I didn't find any related answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please clarify?

Comment: is it possible to replace a script inside DOM?

Comment: In theory, yes. However, there are almost always better ways to accomplish the task.

Comment: how? any recommendation?

Comment: This seems like an example of the XY problem. The XY problem is asking about the solution, not the problem. Could you provide more detail?